# How to allow code block in wordpress comments

Tags: filters, comments, actions

I want to allow users to send code in comments, but WordPress filter that. 
How can I do this?

**UPDATE:**

for example:

I want to send this code snippet in comments, for reply my user:

```
<code>
    <script>
        alert('booooooom');
    </script>
</code>
```

If this code sends by admin, cause to show browser alert. and if the user sends it, filtered by Wordpress.

Comment: Please be more specific. [Edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/286231/edit) to tell us *what* sort of code  you want to allow — HTML, PHP, JS, Java, …?

Comment: I understood the question on my first read of it. And the answer is what he wants.

Answer (score 3):

WordPress allows it by default ( of course, plugins or theme can change that ). The code should be wrapped in `<code></code>`, like this:

```
<code>
global $var;
echo $var;
</code>
```

Comment: Thank you, it does not work! and the theme was written by my self.

Comment: What about plugins? It works on all my sites.

Comment: I installed this plugin and it works. "HTML Code Comments by Ludovic Scribe"